# Question: Python String.split function problem

Tags: python, split

I have a problem like:

```
name = "Steve Jobs is my name."
```

Desired output:

```
['Steve Jobs', 'is', 'my name.']
```

My tried solution:
I have tried using the split function in Python.
Code:

```
result = name.split()
['Steve', 'Jobs', 'is', 'my', 'name']
```

I am unable to proceed from here. I have tried using for loop.
But, I am not getting the required result.

Am I missing something or is there any other way of solving this problem?

Please let me know.

Comment: Why is `my name` expected to be one string?

Comment: What is the rule of splitting? Why are some words kept together and others not?

Comment: This was like a interview question for a company. I have tried, but couldn't solved. Less than a minute was given.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the kind of interview question where they just want to find out how you think. In this case, with just one example to go on, I would look for a pattern that gets you to the desired output.

For example, you could split on `" is "` to get the two parts before and after, then insert `"is"` back in the middle of the list to get the desired result.

```
name = "Steve Jobs is my name."

result = name.split(" is ")
result .insert(1, "is")
print(result )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a trick question:

```
[x.strip() for x in name.partition("is")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split the string using `string.split()`, the string will be split at ever occurrence of `" "` (space). But in your case, you want to split it at a specific place instead of at every occurrence of space.

you can try using:

```
result1 = [name[:10], name[11:13], name[14:]]
```

but this is only applicable if you wanna split this specific string.

If you want to split different strings that are of similar sentence structure, you can try:

```
words = name.split()
result = [words[0] + " " + words[1], words[2], words[3] + " " + words[4]]
```